# Slow MySQL Query on ~400.000 entries

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, where-clause

I have the following query that is really slow (2.9 seg) :

```
SELECT post_id
FROM   ap_props
   LEFT JOIN ap_moneda
          ON ( ap_props.rela_moneda = ap_moneda.id_moneda )
   LEFT JOIN wp_posts
          ON ( ap_props.post_id = wp_posts.id )
WHERE  1 = 1
   AND wp_posts.post_status = "publish"
   AND rela_inmuebleoper = "2"
   AND rela_inmuebletipo = "1"
   AND (( approps_precio * Ifnull(moneda_valor, 0) >= 2000
          AND approps_precio * Ifnull(moneda_valor, 0) <= 6000 ))
   AND rela_barrio IN ( 6, 23085, 23086, 23087,
                        7, 23088, 23089, 23090,
                        23091, 23092, 26, 23115,
                        23116, 23117, 23118, 23119,
                        23120, 32, 43, 23123,
                        23124, 23125 )
   AND ( post_id IS NOT NULL );  

2.90808200
```

The profiling shows :

```
+--------------------------------+----------+
| Status                         | Duration |
+--------------------------------+----------+
| starting                       | 0.000132 |
| checking query cache for query | 0.000135 |
| Opening tables                 | 0.000023 |
| System lock                    | 0.000009 |
| Table lock                     | 0.000033 |
| init                           | 0.000074 |
| optimizing                     | 0.000030 |
| statistics                     | 0.001989 |
| preparing                      | 0.000028 |
| executing                      | 0.000007 |
| Sending data                   | 2.905463 |
| end                            | 0.000015 |
| query end                      | 0.000005 |
| freeing items                  | 0.000055 |
| storing result in query cache  | 0.000013 |
| logging slow query             | 0.000009 |
| logging slow query             | 0.000055 |
| cleaning up                    | 0.000007 |
+--------------------------------+----------+
```

and the explain :

```
+----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type        | possible_keys                                                        | key                                       | key_len | ref                       | rows  | Extra                                                                   |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ap_props  | index_merge | idx_post_id,idx_relabarrio,idx_relainmuebleoper,idx_relainmuebletipo | idx_relainmuebleoper,idx_relainmuebletipo | 5,5     | NULL                      | 58114 | Using intersect(idx_relainmuebleoper,idx_relainmuebletipo); Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ap_moneda | ALL         | NULL                                                                 | NULL                                      | NULL    | NULL                      |     3 | Using where                                                             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | wp_posts  | eq_ref      | PRIMARY                                                              | PRIMARY                                   | 8       | metaprop.ap_props.post_id |     1 | Using where                                                             |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Any ideas on how to improve it? The ammount of entries are ~400.000 in total both in ap_props and wp-posts. ap_moneda only has 5 entries.

I tried removing the IN clause but the following shows the same performance results :

```
SELECT post_id from ap_props left join ap_moneda on (ap_props.rela_moneda = ap_moneda.id_moneda) left join wp_posts on (ap_props.post_id = wp_posts.ID) where 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_status = "publish" AND rela_inmuebleoper = "2" AND rela_inmuebletipo = "1" AND ( ( approps_precio * ifnull(moneda_valor,0) >= 2000 AND approps_precio * ifnull(moneda_valor,0) <= 6000) ) AND (rela_barrio=6 OR rela_barrio=23085 OR rela_barrio=23086 OR rela_barrio=23087 OR rela_barrio=7 OR rela_barrio=23088 OR rela_barrio=23089 OR rela_barrio=23090 OR rela_barrio=23091 OR rela_barrio=23092 OR rela_barrio=26 OR rela_barrio=23115 OR rela_barrio=23116 OR rela_barrio=23117 OR rela_barrio=23118 OR rela_barrio=23119 OR rela_barrio=23120 OR rela_barrio=32 OR rela_barrio=43 OR rela_barrio=23123 OR rela_barrio=23124 OR rela_barrio=23125)  AND (post_id IS NOT NULL);

2.91080400
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Edit :

The current indexes are :

```
+----------+------------+----------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table    | Non_unique | Key_name             | Seq_in_index | Column_name       | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+----------+------------+----------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| ap_props |          0 | PRIMARY              |            1 | approps_origen    | A         |          10 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| ap_props |          0 | PRIMARY              |            2 | approps_id_aviso  | A         |      452098 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| ap_props |          1 | idx_status           |            1 | approps_status_db | A         |           3 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| ap_props |          1 | idx_fecha            |            1 | approps_fecha     | A         |       64585 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| ap_props |          1 | idx_post_id          |            1 | post_id           | A         |      452098 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| ap_props |          1 | idx_relabarrio       |            1 | rela_barrio       | A         |        2457 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| ap_props |          1 | idx_relainmuebleoper |            1 | rela_inmuebleoper | A         |           6 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| ap_props |          1 | idx_relainmuebletipo |            1 | rela_inmuebletipo | A         |          17 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
+----------+------------+----------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

FYI F fixed it by adding a new index idx_approps_precio and forcing both by adding "use index (idx_relabarrio,idx_approps_precio)"

Comment: do you really need `1=1` ?

Comment: I can remove it but it doesn't make a difference in this example.
I tried :)

Comment: if you dont need it why you let query think about it :)

Comment: What are the indexes you have defined on `ap_props`?

Comment: `| ap_props |          0 | PRIMARY              |            1 | approps_origen    | A         |          10 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| ap_props |          0 | PRIMARY              |            2 | approps_id_aviso  | A         |      452087 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| ap_props |          1 | idx_status           |            1 | approps_status_db | A         |           3 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
`

Comment: `| ap_props |          1 | idx_fecha            |            1 | approps_fecha     | A         |       64583 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| ap_props |          1 | idx_post_id          |            1 | post_id           | A         |      452087 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| ap_props |          1 | idx_relabarrio       |            1 | rela_barrio       | A         |        2456 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
`

Comment: `| ap_props |          1 | idx_relainmuebleoper |            1 | rela_inmuebleoper | A         |           6 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| ap_props |          1 | idx_relainmuebletipo |            1 | rela_inmuebletipo | A         |          17 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
`

Comment: Perhaps you can edit your question and include this information in a more legible form?

Comment: Your milliseconds are all in "sending data."  In other words, your time is being taken up by slurping the 400K rows from your MySQL disk drives and sending them over the network to your client.  It may make sense to rethink your problem so you don't have to transport such a large quantity of information. It's hard for us to recommend ways to do that without knowing more about your application.

Answer (score 0):

What if you put the `AND` when joining the tables rather than first join then filters the result set

Give it a try

```
SELECT post_id
FROM   ap_props
   LEFT JOIN ap_moneda
          ON ( ap_props.rela_moneda = ap_moneda.id_moneda  AND `table`.rela_inmuebleoper = "2"   AND `table`.rela_inmuebletipo = "1" )
   LEFT JOIN wp_posts
          ON ( ap_props.post_id = wp_posts.id  AND wp_posts.post_status = "publish")
WHERE  rela_barrio IN ( 6, 23085, 23086, 23087,
                        7, 23088, 23089, 23090,
                        23091, 23092, 26, 23115,
                        23116, 23117, 23118, 23119,
                        23120, 32, 43, 23123,
                        23124, 23125 )      
   AND (( approps_precio * Ifnull(moneda_valor, 0) >= 2000
          AND approps_precio * Ifnull(moneda_valor, 0) <= 6000 ))

   AND ( post_id IS NOT NULL );
```

I have put these two conditions in the join not sure about the table name so you should take care of it `table.rela_inmuebleoper = "2"   AND table.rela_inmuebletipo = "1"` provide the right table name. And also check and made appropriate indexes for the columns

Comment: downvoters please mention my mistakes so that i can improve it

Comment: I haven't downvoted but moving a condition from `WHERE` to `ON` may result in different results with outer joins. I agree that the OP should provide the table design so we know which column belongs to which table.

Comment: You are right but i haven't move all the conditions but just three i.e is `rela_inmuebleoper=1` rela_inmuebleoper = "2" and post_status = "publish" so these are the predefined values so it needs to in join so that table will be joined on that basis after that it can be further filter out

Comment: A little better : 2.29718600, but still slow. Anyway thanks!, it's a plus.

Comment: @KillDash9 now check your indexes

Comment: i commented all the indexes in the main post. I think they are ok.